# Ceph octopus garbage collector makes slow ops

Tags: garbage-collection, ceph

We have a ceph cluster with 408 osds, 3 mons and 3 rgws. We updated our cluster from nautilus 14.2.14 to octopus 15.2.12 a few days ago. After upgrading, the garbage collector process which is run after the lifecycle process, causes slow ops and makes some osds to be restarted. In each process the garbage collector deletes about 1 million objects. Below are the one of the osd's logs before it restarts.

```
2021-07-18T00:44:38.807+0430 7fd1cda76700  1 osd.60 1092400 is_healthy false -- internal heartbeat failed
2021-07-18T00:44:38.807+0430 7fd1cda76700  1 osd.60 1092400 not healthy; waiting to boot
2021-07-18T00:44:39.847+0430 7fd1cda76700  1 heartbeat_map is_healthy 'OSD::osd_op_tp thread 0x7fd1b4243700' had timed out after 15
2021-07-18T00:44:39.847+0430 7fd1cda76700  1 osd.60 1092400 is_healthy false -- internal heartbeat failed
2021-07-18T00:44:39.847+0430 7fd1cda76700  1 osd.60 1092400 not healthy; waiting to boot
2021-07-18T00:44:40.895+0430 7fd1cda76700  1 heartbeat_map is_healthy 'OSD::osd_op_tp thread 0x7fd1b4243700' had timed out after 15
2021-07-18T00:44:40.895+0430 7fd1cda76700  1 osd.60 1092400 is_healthy false -- internal heartbeat failed
2021-07-18T00:44:40.895+0430 7fd1cda76700  1 osd.60 1092400 not healthy; waiting to boot
2021-07-18T00:44:41.859+0430 7fd1cda76700  1 heartbeat_map is_healthy 'OSD::osd_op_tp thread 0x7fd1b4243700' had timed out after 15
2021-07-18T00:44:41.859+0430 7fd1cda76700  1 osd.60 1092400 is_healthy false -- internal heartbeat failed
2021-07-18T00:44:41.859+0430 7fd1cda76700  1 osd.60 1092400 not healthy; waiting to boot
2021-07-18T00:44:42.811+0430 7fd1cda76700  1 heartbeat_map is_healthy 'OSD::osd_op_tp thread 0x7fd1b4243700' had timed out after 15
2021-07-18T00:44:42.811+0430 7fd1cda76700  1 osd.60 1092400 is_healthy false -- internal heartbeat failed
```

what is the suitable configuration for gc in such a heavy delete process so it doesn't make slow ops? We had the same delete load in nautilus but we didn't have any problem with that.

Comment: Have you figured out the solution?

Comment: @Badb0y Not yet